# Windows - Powershell - Configure "Local Group Policy Editor > ... > Account Lockout Policy > Account lockout threshold > invalid logon attempts"

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to find out a **PowerShell Command** to Setup the "**Anti-Brute-Force-login-attempts**" on Windows.

Which is as-is the following manual steps:

1. `gpedit.msc` ( to open "Local Group Policy Editor" )
2. Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Account Policies > Account Lockout Policy > Account lockout threshold > invalid logon attempts
3. Set the "`invalid logon attempts`" to a value, e.g. `3`
4. Done.

---

OS version: Windows 10/11 Pro

Googled a few, didn't find any worked solutions, I hope to have some luck from here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You ca do this from an eevated cmd window using `net accounts`, see [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-restrict-the-number-of-login-attempts-in-windows-7) and [there](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/87609-change-account-lockout-threshold-local-accounts-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
net accounts /lockoutthreshold:3
```

---

Credits: @[Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75299349/windows-powershell-configure-local-group-policy-editor-account-lock#comment132871180_75299349)

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/87609-change-account-lockout-threshold-local-accounts-windows-10-a.html